# VS CodeでUTF-32を開く方法

Tags: vscode, unicode

Visual Studio Codeを使用してUTF-32で記述されたファイルを開くにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: こんな記事を応用してカスタマイズするとか？ [VSCodeの文字コード自動判定を改善する](https://7cc.hatenadiary.jp/entry/modify_vscode_autoguessencoding_), [vscode の ShiftJIS 自動判定を矯正するためにソースからビルドする](https://gist.github.com/shspage/d119133c18bba852e324b02e12668c5e)

Comment: ここ [vscode/src/vs/base/node/encoding.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/base/node/encoding.ts) にこんな記述 `// - UTF-32: we do not support this encoding in VSCode` があるので、標準のままや多少の設定変更程度ではサポートされない可能性が高そうです。

Comment: なるほどサポートされていないのですね。今後サポートされる事を願っていようと思います。

Comment: VS Code と `iconv` を使用している環境が不明ですが、私が使用している Linux (x86_64) 環境の iconv のライブラリディレクトリ(/usr/lib64/gconv)には UTF-32.so が存在し、`iconv -l` に UTF-32, UTF-32BE, UTF-32LE がありましたので、iconv であれば UTF8 や UTF-16 に変換できそうです。

Answer (score -1):

**解決していません。以下の回答は「UTF-32で記述されたファイルを開く」方法ではありませんでした**

`UTF-16`のファイルを開くためのプラグインをいれた記憶がありません。
普通に開けばよいと思います。

- `ファイル`メニューの`ファイルを開く`

ファイルを開くと、ウィンドウ下端のステータスバーに`UTF-16 LE`か`UTF-16 BE`と表示されます。

Comment: UTF-32 の話なんぢゃ？（物理ファイルが UTF-32 ってのはかなりレアな話だけど）

Comment: すみません、おっしゃるとおりです。

Comment: 解決が難しそうです。VSCODEでエディタの内容をiconvなどで変換できないか調べてみましたがいまのところあたりがつきません。